# Callback Function from Server in Codename one iOS build

Tags: java, android, ios, netbeans, codenameone

Callback functions from server works perfectly android devices but do not work on iOS devices.
Please can you help me with this issue
Thank you

Comment: I'll need more information to help you here such as what API are you calling and what callback are you expecting from the server? Notice that HTTP doesn't send callbacks so all callbacks are from the client

Comment: public MyConnectionRequest2(Callback call) {
        super();
        setReadTimeout(Main.timeout);
        setTimeout(Main.timeout);
        this.fcall = call;
        this.scall = call;
    }

Comment: this is a sample code... but this works perfectly on android devices.... but not on ios devices.... is there a build hint that relates to network related callbacks for ios?

Comment: You don't pass the callback to our code. You use it within `MyConnectionRequest`. You need to edit the question and include proper code we can follow to understand the problem. There are differences between iOS and Android but they are nuanced... Is the URL HTTPS based?

Comment: Thanks, Shai.. I realized the timeout for ios on connections is only one minute. after one minute the connection closes

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` and `setReadTimeout` explicitly to whatever you want.